# Finding a recursive definition and computing $B(10)$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, recursive-algorithms

For $n \geq 1$, let $B(n)$ be the number of ways to express $n$ as the sum of $1$s and $2$s, taking order into account. Thus $B(4) = 5$ because $4 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 1 + 1 + 2 = 1 + 2 + 1 = 2 + 1 + 1 = 2 + 2$.

(a) Compute $B(i)$ for $1 \leq i \leq 5$ by showing all the different ways to write these numbers as above.

(b) Find a recursive definition for $B(n)$ and identify this sequence.

(c) Compute $B(10)$.

I've done part (a)

$B(1) = 1$ because $1 = (1)$

$B(2) = 2$ because $2 = (1+1) = (2)$

$B(3) = 3$ because $3 = (1+1+1) = (1+2) = (2+1)$

$B(4) = 5$ because $4 = (1 + 1 + 1 + 1) = (1 + 1 + 2) = (1 + 2 + 1) = (2 + 1 + 1) = (2 + 2)$

$B(5) = 8$ because $$5 = (1+1+1+1+1) = (1+1+1+2) = (1+1+2+1) = (1+2+1+1)\\ = (2+1+1+1) = (1+2+2) = (2+1+2) = (2+2+1)$$

*Note I used parenthesis for clarity

How would I do part B?

Comment: You have a typo in $B(5)$ as $1+2+2$ occurs twice, $2+2+1$ never

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: There are two questions for you to answer. Suppose that $n\ge 3.$ How many ways are there to obtain $n$ as such a sum where the first number is $1$? What if the first number is $2$? What can you then conclude?

Comment: Sorry I was busy. Um so would $B(1) = 1$ and $B(2) = 2$?

Comment: Yes, because $1=(1)$ and $2=(1+1)=(2).$

Comment: Also, if you allow an "[empty sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum)," we have $B(0)=1.$ Hence, the first several terms of the sequence are $1,1,2,3,5,8.$ Do those look familiar?

Comment: Isn't that like the beginning of the Fibonacci sequence?

Comment: It is *exactly* the beginning of the Fibonacci sequence. Unless you're used to the Fibonacci sequence starting with a $0$, in which case we can fix that by noting that $B(-1)=0.$

Comment: Oh, so would the recursive definition then be $B_n = B_{n-1} + B_{n-2}$ for $n \geq 3$. And then $B(10)$ would be $89$. Yes?

Comment: Yes, but do you see why? Can you justify it using the hint that I provided?